# Webpack output two builds, one for ES6, one for IE11

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a webpack configuration of ES5/ES6 modules that works fairly well. Until recently it also ran through TargetsPlugin to generate a IE11-compatible build.

I say "until recently" because while experimenting, I noticed that dropping the babel transpiling to older language specs, we instantly shed 300KB from our bundles. If we turned this on, 90-point-something percent of our users would get a leaner, faster, *better* experience.

#### But I'm contractually obliged to support IE11. Can I do that separately?

What I want is a ES6-ish build (what we have) and a companion IE11 build. It's not difficult to target these browsers programmatically when it comes to switching out what version they see... But how do I get webpack to do it?

If it makes any difference, I don't need the IE11 version to have any fancy features. It can be one 1MB amorphous blob, or fully chunked out. However it comes, as long as it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, turns out webpack can handle multiple configs at the same time. Where you would normally do `module.exports = { ... config ... }`, you can actually return an array of config objects.

So I went for something like this:

```
var realConfig = {
  ...
}

var ie11 = _.cloneDeep(real)
ie11.output.filename = 'js/ie11.[name].js'

ie11.plugins.push(
  new TargetsPlugin({ browsers: ["IE >= 11"] })
)

module.exports = [ realConfig, ie11 ]
```

And that gives me an IE-compatible version of everything. In my templates I just detect "MSIE" in the user agent and feed that out. Probably not the most reliable but build should also work on modern browsers so I'm not concerned.